# \thanks{} creates duplicate footnotes in AAAI21 sty

Tags: pdftex, footnotes, affiliation

I am using the AAA21 style file (aaai21.sty) with article document class. When putting multiple `\thanks{}` on the authors, I get duplicate footnote text on the 1st page.

- [Link](https://pastebin.com/s8REZcjW) to the `sty` file.
- You can find the full latex template [here](https://www.aaai.org/Publications/Templates/AuthorKit21.zip). Look inside the **Latex** folder.

This is the latex I am using,

```
\title{-------}
\author{
    % Authors
    Auth 1\footnote{equal contribution}\textsuperscript{\rm 3}\footnote{work done as part of},
    Auth 2\footnotemark[1]\textsuperscript{\rm 2}\thanks{work done while a},
    Auth 3\footnotemark[1]\textsuperscript{\rm 1},
    Auth 4\textsuperscript{\rm 4}\footnotemark[2],
    Auth 5\textsuperscript{\rm 1},
    Auth 6\textsuperscript{\rm 1}\\
}
\affiliations{
    % Affiliations
    \textsuperscript{\rm 1} Aff 1 \\
    \textsuperscript{\rm 2} Aff 2 \\
    \textsuperscript{\rm 3} Aff 3 \\
    \textsuperscript{\rm 4} Aff 4 \\
    a@gmail.com, b@gmail.com, c@gmail.com, d@gmail.com,  e@gmail.com, f@gmail.com
}
```

And here is the rendered output which has duplicate footnote text. Can somebody point out why this is happening?
I tried to look at the `sty` file but possibly it is fine. You can obtain the `aaai21.sty` file online.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is the file `aaai21.sty` available online? If so, where?

Comment: Here is the [link](https://www.aaai.org/Publications/Templates/AuthorKit21.zip) to the author kit. You can find the file `aaai.sty` inside the `Latex` folder. I have added the link in the OP as well.

Comment: This duplication business looks like a bug. Bug reports should be addressed to the author(s) of the package in question. They're off-topic for TeX.SE.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try to report this to the authors, but can you look at the sty file and suggest a fix? It seems not too long for someone who regularly "codes" in latex. I am actually trying to use this template for something else.

Comment: Here is the `sty` file https://pastebin.com/s8REZcjW

Comment: they probably mean `\let\footnote\relax\let\thanks\relax` in the \@maketitle definition, but you should really report this, it will affect every author. Also their formatting instructions errors as the \author examples contain empty lines.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That fixes the issue!! Thanks a lot, Ulrike.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Ulrike in the comments of the original post, changing `\let\footnote\thanks\relax` to `\let\footnote\relax\let\thanks\relax` fixes the issue.

Comment: then report it. The text is quite strict on that the style should not be changed.

Comment: Yes, I saw that! I actually am planning to use the PDF for some other purpose. I already sent an email, hope those guys fix it on time.