# Modify \maketitle in report to avoid duplicated thanks (overleaf)

Tags: report, author, affiliation

I am using the `report` class. I have several chapters, and in each chapter I use a separate title page. To insert affiliations in the authors, I use each time `\author{SOMEONE\thanks{affiliations}}`.

This works perfectly fine, but in each subsequent chapter, each new chapter title page duplicates the thanks including the ones with the previous chapters. I found out that to solve the issue it should be enough to add something like `\let\footnote\relax\let\thanks\relax` in the `\maketitle` definition as suggested here [\thanks{} creates duplicate footnotes in AAAI21 sty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/561067/thanks-creates-duplicate-footnotes-in-aaai21-sty). However, I cannot find how to access the latter. Can I somehow define a `\renewcommand` to do this? I am using Overleaf so I don't know how to access the `\maketitle`

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref,todonotes,longtable}
\usepackage{graphics,epsfig,lscape,setspace,url,setspace,morefloats,comment,booktabs,color}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[labelfont=sc, singlelinecheck=false, font={small}]{caption}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[flushmargin,hang,marginal,multiple, stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{titling}

\hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 0}}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\bf ABSTRACT}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2em]
  {\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}%
   \def\chapquote@author{#2}%
   \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax%
   \itshape}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill \chapquote@author\hspace*{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{plain}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\bf ABSTRACT}

\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother

\title{main title\\
{\Large somewhere}}
\author{Author 1}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{My chapter 1}
\title{\LARGE{\bf My chap 1 \vspace{0.5cm}} }
\author{\small \sc{Author1\thanks{Affiliation 1}}} %to mute
\date{}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}{\noindent An abstract
\blfootnote{We thank X} %to mute
}
\end{abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty} \newpage
\section{Sec1}   
\section{Sec2}   

\chapter{My chapter 2}
\title{\LARGE{\bf My chap 2 \vspace{0.5cm}} }
\author{\small \sc{Author2\thanks{Affiliation 2}}} %to mute
\date{}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}{\noindent An abstract
\blfootnote{We thank X} %to mute
}
\end{abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty} \newpage
\section{Sec1}   
\section{Sec2}   

\chapter{My chapter 3}
\title{\LARGE{\bf My chap 3 \vspace{0.5cm}} }
\author{\small \sc{Author3\thanks{Affiliation 3}}} %to mute
\date{}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}{\noindent An abstract
\blfootnote{We thank X} %to mute
}
\end{abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty} \newpage
\section{Sec1}   
\section{Sec2}   


\end{document}
```

As you can see, the third chapter has the affiliations of the previous 2 chapters' authors

[image]

Comment: Hi, please provide a compilable MWE, so we can reproduce and track the error. Adding `\let\footnote\relax...` shouldn't change anything, because these commands are already part of the default definition for `\maketitle` in the `report` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using the `titling` package, you have to insert an `\emptythanks` command after every use of `\maketitle` with a `\thanks`:

```latex
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref,todonotes,longtable}
\usepackage{graphics,epsfig,lscape,setspace,url,setspace,morefloats,comment,booktabs,color}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[labelfont=sc, singlelinecheck=false, font={small}]{caption}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[flushmargin,hang,marginal,multiple, stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{titling}

\hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 0}}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\bf ABSTRACT}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2em]
  {\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}%
   \def\chapquote@author{#2}%
   \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax%
   \itshape}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill \chapquote@author\hspace*{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{plain}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\bf ABSTRACT}

\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother

\title{main title\\
{\Large somewhere}}
\author{Author 1}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{My chapter 1}
\title{\LARGE{\bf My chap 1 \vspace{0.5cm}} }
\author{\small \sc{Author1\thanks{Affiliation 1}}} %to mute
\date{}
\maketitle\emptythanks % <--- always emptythanks after \maketitle
\begin{abstract}{\noindent An abstract
\blfootnote{We thank X} %to mute
}
\end{abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\section{Sec1}   
\section{Sec2}   

\chapter{My chapter 2}
\title{\LARGE{\bf My chap 2 \vspace{0.5cm}} }
\author{\small \sc{Author2\thanks{Affiliation 2}}} %to mute
\date{}
\maketitle\emptythanks % <--- !
\begin{abstract}{\noindent An abstract
\blfootnote{We thank X} %to mute
}
\end{abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty} \newpage
\section{Sec1}   
\section{Sec2}   

\chapter{My chapter 3}
\title{\LARGE{\bf My chap 3 \vspace{0.5cm}} }
\author{\small \sc{Author3\thanks{Affiliation 3}}} %to mute
\date{}
\maketitle\emptythanks % <--- !
\begin{abstract}{\noindent An abstract
\blfootnote{We thank X} %to mute
}
\end{abstract}
\thispagestyle{empty} \newpage
\section{Sec1}   
\section{Sec2}   


\end{document}
```

Its always a good idea to take a look inside the docs of the packages used in your document ;) The `titling` doc explicitly states the need of `\emptythanks` on page 7!

Off topic, but nevertheless good to know: Don't use commands like `\bf` for bold, or `\sc` for small caps, but the more up-to-date and therefore safer commands `\textbf{}`/`\bfseries` and `\textsc{}`/`\scshape`.

Comment: that indeed fixes the problem perfectly. Thanks a lot!